# How to make symmetric draws in c#

Tags: c#

I have to make a project on "symmetry" theme in c#. I chose to make a symmetric draw. You draw on the left part and it will appear a symmetric drawing on the right one! How to make this with 2 split containers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many types of symmetry.

Take a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(geometry)

Assuming you just want mirror symmetry, for every point (`left_x`,`left_y`) in your left container, the corresponding point in your right container (`right_x`,`right_y`) will be calculated as follows:

```
right_y = left_y;
right_x = width_of_right_container - left_x;
```

Comment: How can I make a drawing in c# in my app not in my code? I'm sorry but I'm a starter.

Comment: I think you should have started working on this on Friday, not on Sunday evening.

Comment: srsly help me. I'm just a starter

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  You write your code yourself, you try your best, and if it does not work, then you bring it to stackoverflow asking what's wrong with it.